# what does "vertiginous game of chicken" mean and its origin

Tags: meaning

Taking us behind the scenes, Paulson shows, day by day, how the U.S. government and Federal Reserve got sucked into a vertiginous game of chicken with Wall Street bankers ([link](http://noir.bloomberg.com/apps/news?pid=20601088&sid=aFJfPdMMN0Lk))

Comment: I just want to note that the sentence you cite mixes its metaphors rather badly. First we have "behind the scenes" conjuring up acting, then we have "sucked into a vertiginous" giving us whirlpool imagery, then we have a "game of chicken" which invokes a teenage driving game from the 1950s (see http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048545/). The editor should be chastised for not reining it all in.

Comment: Yes, George Orwell would include it in his index. http://www.mtholyoke.edu/acad/intrel/orwell46.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the definitions cited by RegDwight, I would explain the sentence as follows.

The bankers' actions put them on a collision course with the government and the Fed.

The potential for disaster was so great that all involved got dizzy thinking about the worst possible results.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_%28game%29):

> The name "Chicken" has its origins in a game in which two drivers drive towards each other on a collision course: one must swerve, or both may die in the crash, but if one driver swerves and the other does not, the one who swerved will be called a "chicken," meaning a coward; this terminology is most prevalent in political science and economics.

*Vertiginious* comes from *vertigo*, so it's something that's whirling around, causing dizziness.

Comment: +RegDwight - why does being "chicken" mean being a coward?  It is also prevalent on the playground.  Maybe it should be its own question?